# How to get ordered list of items bases on users data from MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mongodb

I have list of users in my mongoDB as follows:

```
 user1{
    username,
    password,
    likedItems[item1, item2]
 }

 user2{
    username,
    password,
    likedItems[item1]
 }
```

and I want to get a list of most liked items. in this example it would be item1 first then item2.
I am doing this inside of a spring boot application and at the moment, I iterate over every user and I get his liked items and add them into a
     Map with key:item and value: count

I am asking if there is a cleaner way of achieving this using only mongodb repository.

EDIT: json document example

```
{
  "_id": "5a68a9308117670afc3522cd",
  "_class": "com.auth.auth2.entities.User",
  "username": "user1",
  "password": "$2a$10$8QeAFaAAhfwu8jMxynPbtOAyHLcb0s8a0m6ilbz9QY.DzCqGUsFwe",
  "roles": [
    {
      "_id": null,
      "name": "USER"
    },
    {
      "_id": null,
      "name": "ACTUATOR"
    }
  ],
  "favoriteItems": {
    "5a0c6711fb3aac66aafe26c6": {
      "_id": "5a0c6711fb3aac66aafe26c6",
      "name": "item1",
    },
    "5a0c6b83fd3eb67969316dd7": {
      "_id": "5a0c6b83fd3eb67969316dd7",
      "name": "item2",
    },
    "5a0c6b83fd3eb67969316de4": {
      "_id": "5a0c6b83fd3eb67969316de4",
      "name": "item3"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you implement a counter against each item. You can increment the count of likes of each item when it is liked by a user. Then retrieving of items in the order of likes is a snap.

Comment: can you post a sample document in json format?

Comment: Take a look at mongodb aggregation doc. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/
you can do this with Map-Reduce.